# How does one unlock a Volus Adept?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

The official OXM magazine says:

> Recruit Packs will help you flesh out your arsenal, but it's probably worth saving for the better Reinforcement Packs. Rare weapons make a big difference in battle, and you'll also have a better chance of **unlocking new characters like the surprisingly cute Volus Adept**. Unlike in the world of football stickers, duplicate items aren't a problem - get the same gun twice, and it will merely upgrade the original weapon. If you've already unlocked the character on a card, you'll get training instead, giving that class a whopping XP bonus and unlocking new appearance options.

http://www.oxm.co.uk/39460/features/mass-effect-3-multiplayer-guide-dlc-unlocks-guns-classes-and-items/?page=2

How do you unlock this race, or how rare is it?

Comment: I've seen no other source for a Volus Adept (or room for it on the selection screen), I'm not sure this is real

Comment: There doesn't have to be room; I believe there is no "room" for the Battlefield class but that is still real and gets added to the side if you have it.

Comment: It's widely regarded as either a myth, misprint or intentional troll.  [For example](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995452-/62193176)

Comment: well if they're rare, I'd certainly assume you need to get the Spectre packs to unlock them. They're not listed anywhere at any authoritative sources though, like the wiki: http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer#Pack_Contents

Comment: I'm guessing they're trolling in reference to the Volus from ME2 who thought he was the most powerful biotic in the world.

Comment: Also, considering [this is what Volus look like](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Volus), I'm inclined to believe it's simply someone who doesn't know their terminology, and they're referring to the Asari

Comment: This feels like a joke, as volus make for incredibly bad ground soldiers when not in their native environment (hell, even in their native environment).  Puncture a volus' enviro suit in a nitrogen/oxygen environment at 1 atm, and a volus will explode.  Not the kind of person you want on a battlefield

Comment: @MBraedley I dunno about you, but I'd sure want a [Biotic God](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bH-8fzQechY) on my side...

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Yeah, because an extremely fragile person hopped up on an extremely addictive drug is a good thing...

Comment: Well... Um... Yes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of the [Retaliation DLC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Khw4Er_q6gA) there actually *is* a Volus adept for multiplayer along with the DLC's content. I believe it is unlockable like the other classes via random items but I'm not sure of the specifics yet.

---

(Earlier answer retained for posterity; in the base content no Volus Adept existed)

There's no such thing as a Volus Adept in multiplayer.

As you can see from the list of Multiplayer objects from ME3, this class/race combo doesn't exist (note the "secret" Battlefield 3 character IS in the list):
[image]

The magazine was probably trolling or wasn't familiar with the race names, I assume they're referring to the Asari adept. It's been noted in the series that the [Volus](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Volus) are terrible ground troops in low-pressure environment (eg anything a human can survive in), and there's never been a Volus in combat in the whole series, so it's extremely unlikely they'd implement one.

In addition, the only mumblings of a Volus Adept are in reference to this exact magazine piece, so I'd say Successful Troll is Successful.

Comment: Woo, science. +1

Comment: I do remember a certain drugged up volus attempting a puny little bio push in ME2 though, that scene was funny :)

Comment: Since this was bumped, but this is a good answer, you should update this - there actually ARE playable Volus in the Retaliation DLC.

Answer (score 5):

While it is possible that a Volus Adept was once a consideration, they are not in multiplayer, so it is likely a joke and a reference to [Niftu Cal](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Niftu_Cal), the drugged-up self-proclaimed "[biotic god](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgGV0pfbcxg)" found during Samara's recruitment in Mass Effect 2.

Comment: that was the one I was thinking of, good old Niftu, he sure didn't last long though.